# Use Rack::Static to mount a directory outside of the project directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack, rails-engines, webpacker

I'm building a Rails Engine that includes some assets built through Webpacker, and I'm following [the Webpacker documentation](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/master/docs/engines.md#use-a-separate-middleware) on this.

I would like to distribute this engine as a gem, and to serve the engine's assets directly from the engine's gem, through a `Rack::Static` middleware in the host application.

This is what I'm trying:

```rb
# in the engine project: lib/my_engine/engine.rb
module MyEngine
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
    (...)
    config.app_middleware.use(
      Rack::Static,
      urls: ['/myengine'], root: File.join(__dir__, 'public')
    )
  end
end
```

If I set the `root:` option for `Rack::Static` to a relative path (eg: `my_engine/public`) and then create a symlink in the host project to the relevant directory in the gem, this will work, however the code above, which generates an absolute path, does not work.

What could I do to fix this?

Comment: Did you ever break ground on this? I'm running into a related issue where I have a `Rack::Static` wrapper that I mount in my routes as `mount Rerackt::UI.new, at: "/rerackt"`, where `Rerackt::UI` passes an absolute root to `Rack::Static`. This actually works if I mount it at `"/"`, but when I mount it at `"/rerackt"` the assets linked to in `index.html` are, e.g. `/static/...chunk.js` when they need to be `/rerackt/static/...chunk.js`

Answer (score 1):

root: MyEngine::Engine.root.join("public")

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please elaborate more on how your answer will fix the issue.